# Passing double pointer as function argument

Tags: c, pointers

I simply want to assign a pointer to another pointer via the function (same memory address). My code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void d(int** a)
{
    int* val_ptr = malloc(1);
    *val_ptr   = 5;
    printf("%d\n", *val_ptr);

    a = &val_ptr;
}

int main()
{
    int* a = NULL;
    d(&a);
    printf("%d\n", *a);
    return 0;
}
```

Output from [Link](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler)

```
5
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: `a = &val_ptr;` should be `*a = val_ptr;`. Otherwise, you're just setting the local copy of a, instead of changing the pointer pointed to by a.

Comment: @Tyker If they implement what I said in my comment, the `a` in `main` will contain the address returned by `malloc`. What they have now won't cause out-of-scope issues, no value form `main` ever gets changed by the call to `d`.

Comment: @Tyker It's not bad, it just won't work because `a` in that scope is a variable local to the function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code has three problems:

1. Here `int* val_ptr = malloc(1);`, you allocate 1 byte rather than allocating space for an `int`. Use the following to fix it:

   ```
   int* val_ptr = malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
   ```
2. This `a = &val_ptr;` is not what you want. It changes the local pointer and makes it point to the address of `val_ptr`. This will *not* affect the pointer that you've defined in `main`.

   Fix it using

   ```
   *a = val_ptr;
   ```

   This way, the pointer in `main` will also reflect the change and will point to the `malloc`ed memory
3. You should `free` the allocated memory after its use. Add

   ```
   free(a);
   ```

   after the `printf` in `main` to free it.